# Replicate up, down, left, right UI selection in code for use with voice control

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sendkeys

I have a unity project and we are tasked with adding simple voice controlled up, down, left, right UI selection functionality. This is to replicate the up, down, left, right key press functionality.

I do not have an issue with getting voice recognition working. I just can't figure out how to move selection up, down, left or right in code. Frustratingly, I cannot find information on how to replicate the arrow key presses. I expected to be able to use SendKeys() but this does not appear to be available in Unity. Is there a way to do this in Unity?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to work out the voice recognition part yourself, as I've only worked with it briefly, but I suspect that the "ok, now that I know that the user said 'next' I am not sure how to go to the next field" part is what you need help with.

```
Selectable selected = EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.GetComponent<Selectable>();
```

This will get the instance of the [`Selectable`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable.html) component of whatever is currently selected. This could be a button, an input field, or something else. There are a bunch of things that inherit from it.

Now, navigating:

```
selected.FindSelectableOnLeft();
selected.FindSelectableOnRight();
selected.FindSelectableOnUp();
selected.FindSelectableOnDown();
```

And there's your four directions. Once you have a Selectable to target, just call [`Select()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable.Select.html) on it.

Not all of these are guaranteed to be non-null (and even `selected` may be null!) so you'll want to perform null checks before doing anything else.

Hopefully that fills in the missing pieces.

Comment: Excellent! That looks exactly like what I need. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, it was something I had to mess with when I built a big grid of input fields with code (even though it was static, there were 12 input fields and 24 buttons that all basically did the same thing and I didn't want to build it by hand) and I wanted Tab to tab through the input fields and skip the buttons (which were just +1/-1 accessors to their associated field).